# Error when inserting a image in code from Placeholder.com

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a budding programmer and I have problems inserting an image from placeholder.com into my code.

It keeps returning an error saying

> You need to have a .user-photo DIV and an image inside it

Below is the block of code I wrote:

```html
<div class ="user-photo">
  <img src ="https://www.placeholder.com/150" alt= "user photo">
</div>
```

Comment: _"It keeps returning an error"_ What keeps doing this? BTW, the proper URL is https://via.placeholder.com/150

Comment: I'm taking an assessment on a platform - Gradr. 

I have tried all the suggested fixes but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the src is wrong:

```html
<div class="user-photo">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="user photo">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and even used other image services. I still get the same error. I have looked at the whole code countless times. What else could be wrong, please?

Comment: Maybe you can give some more details of where the error is comming from

Comment: I'm taking an assessment on a platform - Gradr. I have tried all the suggested fixes but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dimeji You're providing too little details for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL to use to link to an image from placeholder.com is `https://via.placeholder.com/150`

Notice the `via` subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

With your service something wrong... Try other service, for example https://placehold.it/150

```
<div class ="user-photo">
    <img src ="https://placehold.it/150" alt= "user photo">
</div>
```